# If not explicitly defined, what is the default lifetime for a service in aspnetcore?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I understand the 3 major lifetimes:

1. Singleton
2. Scoped
3. Transient

But I can't seem to find documentation that state what the default lifetime is if not explicitly defined.

Comment: To close voters: Just the fact that the question says they can't find the documentation doesn't make this a resource request. This question is asking for information, not where to find that information (i.e. it's not a resource request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the lifetime of a registered type is Transient i.e. each time the type of object is injected a new instance is created.

The documentation for injection lifetimes are here...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options

> Transient
>
> Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested.
>   This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.
>
> Scoped
>
> Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.
>
> Singleton
>
> Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they're
>   requested (or when ConfigureServices is run if you specify an instance
>   there) and then every subsequent request will use the same instance

aspnetcore's service registration requires you to explicitly define lifetimes using methods such as

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddScoped<IRoleHelper, PermissionRoleHelper>();
services.AddSingleton<IPermissionHelper, ApplicationPermissions>();
```

3rd party injection frameworks such as autofac will register objects as transient without explicitly defining an alternate lifetime scope for the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you pinpoint within the documentation that specifically says that the default is Transient?

Comment: @GaryBrunton If you're using aspnetcores service registration framework then there isn't really such a thing as a default as the syntax forces you to explicitly define the lifetime of the object.  Without an injection framework all types are transient.